# Entity Framework Core generating -ve integer values for Primary Key column on a table row add

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using EF Core v2.2 for inserting and updating rows into a table.

While I am doing that, I am looping based on a list and trying to insert into the table. For the 1st row insert the code works as expected.

However from the second item in the list the row doesn't get inserted into the table.

When I debugged, I found out that after the _rmsContext.save() the 2nd inserts the primary key value for the table is generated as `-9223372036854774802`.

Here is my code

```
foreach (string account in accntList)
{
     var crossBowAccounts = _cbContext.SomeTableRepository
                                      .FindBy(ca => ca.AccountId == account && 
                                                    ca.ClientId == model.ClientId)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();

     AccountHistory accountHistory = new AccountHistory()
                            {
                                AccountId = account,
                                ClientId = model.ClientId,
                                UserId = userId,
                                ActionName = crossBowAccounts == null ? "Add" : "Edit"
                            };

     _rmsContext.AccountHistoryRepository.Add(accountHistory);
     _rmsContext.Save();

     // Some more insert/update code for a table in a different context .
    _rmsContext.Save();
}
```

Here `model` is being passed as an input to the method.

This is what I observed during debugging:

[image]

This is my table schema

[image]

Comment: `AccountHistoryId` is primary key column with Identity configured?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, i have updated my post with the screen shot of table schema.

Comment: The code throws any error when `AccountHistoryId` has negative value? Does `AccountHistoryId` has valid value after `_rmsContext.Save();` is executed?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are hitting this issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6147

> EF Core generates temporary IDs which are then replaced with the real IDs when SaveChanges is called

It's not exactly a bug and it has been changed again in 3.1.

So until the item is inserted, a negative and/or random number makes sense. You need to see why it's not inserted (the negative id is not the reason).

Comment: I may have not conveyed correctly, but the -ve value is generated after the _context.save() is executed. i.e. for the 2nd item in the loop.

Comment: I got that, but I'm pretty sure that it isn't saved. Can you share the Repository code? Maybe we can figure out why the new object is not attached to the context or why the   save is not done.

Answer (score 1):

it is not bug, id is generated randomly before call **SaveChanges** method. If  you do debug after SaveChanges, Id will be correct.

Comment: I may have not conveyed correctly before, but the -ve value is generated after the _context.save() is executed. The screen shot that i have shared is after savechanges is executed.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr hmm, did you check mapping ?